# Python - join two dataframes by the same number

Tags: python, join

I have two data frames:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | q |
| 1 | w |
| 1 | e |
| 2 | r |
| 2 | t |
| 3 | y |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | x |

and

| A | D |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ! |
| 2 | @ |
| 3 | % |

I want to join in python those data frames into one like:

| A | B | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | q | ! |
| 1 | w | ! |
| 1 | e | ! |
| 2 | r | @ |
| 2 | t | @ |
| 3 | y | % |
| 3 | b | % |
| 4 | x |  |

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='A')
```

gives:

```
   A   B    D
0   1  q    !
1   1  w    !
2   1  e    !
3   2  r    @
4   2  t    @
5   3  y    %
6   3  b    %
7   4  x  NaN
```